# Cancel global css inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance, reset, tablelayout

I have a global reset rule:

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

I also have a LOT of tables with pre-defined cellpadding values. However, the global reset rule is killing all the cellpadding values. What would be the best way to get the cellpadding back without having to create a specific css rule for each table? (There are a **lot** of tables.)

**EDIT**: to clarify, if I took out the `padding:0px;` rule then all the tables would look perfect. But, I still need the global reset for other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a reset sheet like [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), and cut-out tables from there.

What is odd is that inline formatting should be trumping global formatting.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking... I guess the global css trumps the old-school table HTML styles - technically not inline css, right? 

So I guess this would be about the only way to do it... change the reset rules so that tables are excluded?

Answer (score 0):

```
table
{
  padding: 3px;
}
```

and/or possibly

```
table tr
{
  padding: 3px;
}
```

and/or possibly td, th and all other table related elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would work great except each table uses a different cellpadding.